# how to change character in phaser js i face issue

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I set value of character but first time is work fine charter changed but when gameover then if i change the character value will be changed but character still same which i choose first time.

```
    this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, -500, this.charSelect).setOrigin(1, 1);
    this.player.body.setGravityY(1700);
    this.player.setBounce(0.1);

    this.physics.add.existing(this.player).body.setSize(15, 90, ).setOffset(20, 0)
```

this.charSelect is the variable where charachter name are stored. the value of this.charSelect is change but character still same

```
    this.load.spritesheet("dude-1", "../src/assets/Character/ch-1.png", {
        frameWidth: 72,
        frameHeight: 92,

    });

    this.load.spritesheet("dude-2", "../src/assets/Character/ch-2.png", {
        frameWidth: 72,
        frameHeight: 92,

    });
    this.load.spritesheet("dude-3", "../src/assets/Character/ch-3.png", {
        frameWidth: 72,
        frameHeight: 92,

    });
    this.load.spritesheet("dude-4", "../src/assets/Character/ch-4.png", {
        frameWidth: 72,
        frameHeight: 92,

    });
    this.load.spritesheet("dude-5", "../src/assets/Character/ch-5.png", {
        frameWidth: 72,
        frameHeight: 92,

    });
    this.load.spritesheet("dude-6", "../src/assets/Character/ch-6.png", {
        frameWidth: 72,
        frameHeight: 92,

    });
    this.load.spritesheet("dude-7", "../src/assets/Character/ch-7.png", {
        frameWidth: 72,
        frameHeight: 92,

    });
    this.load.spritesheet("dude-8", "../src/assets/Character/ch-8.png", {
        frameWidth: 72,
        frameHeight: 92,

    });
```

here is above  character loading in spritesheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to call the function `setTexture` of the sprite object, to change the texture. [here is the link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite.html#setTexture__anchor), after the reselecting of a new character, or restarting of the game:

```
 this.player.setTexture(this.charSelect);
```

**Update:** As aspected the Error has to do with the animations. Since Animations are based/attached on the `game` object, not the `scene` (details [in the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Animations.AnimationManager.html)), you would have to *remove* the animations before recreating them.

Just add this lines, into the `GameScene.js` before creating the `anims`, before the **line 93**:

```
    this.anims.remove('left');
    this.anims.remove('right');
    this.anims.remove('turn');
```

Comment: still same not worked

Comment: this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, -500, this.charSelect).setOrigin(1, 1);

        this.player.setTexture(this.charSelect);
        
        this.player.body.setGravityY(1700);
code here

Comment: @ArslanArshad there is not link in your last comment. btw.: are you using animations? if so you would have to use differnet animation, since it still reference the old sprite.

Comment: i'm not using animations

Comment: Texture.frame missing: main
this error appearing in console

Comment: well than _this.charSelect_ is not the name/key of the sprite. what is the value of that property? btw.: in the code of a earlier question of yours, you are using `this.anims.create` [link to older post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72344240/1679286)

Comment: in `this.charSelect` value is dude-1 if selected 1 
 `this.load.spritesheet("dude-1", "../src/assets/Character/ch-1.png", {
            frameWidth: 72,
            frameHeight: 92,

        });`

Comment: i use webpacks  in game i implement all try but still same not worked please give me solution ?

Comment: @ArslanArshad I would like to help, but there is not enough code to find the problem.

Comment: let me upload on git

Comment: here is code  please ho this link

[link]we.tl/t-KeUyHGb4ck

Comment: please download code

Comment: I updated the answer, the problem is the animations, since they are global. P.s.: usually I don't (in Stackoverflow) it is not common the debug code, but I was bored today morning. :) You could also checkout https://phaser.discourse.group/, there are many Phaser developers.