# How to swtich image in phaser js?

Tags: phaser-framework

**How to swtich image in phaser js?**
I change profile image but its showing still same but when reload the game image has been changed

Comment: @winner_joiner give me answer?

Comment: Without more context your question cannot be answered, but my initial thought would be like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72773979/1679286, but I assume this wont work. In any case check out this article on how to ask question on Stackoverflow and recieving an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask following this "rules" will help you get answers faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the little details you provided, I think you're looking for `Image.setTexture(key: string)`. This method will set the texture used by an image GameObject to that of "key".